# Swift CLI : Redirecting textfile(input) into program

Tags: swift, redirect, command-line-interface

> ./some_program < some_text_input

Like above, i want a txt file to be redirected into program using swift.

i'd googled lots of things but i havent found anything...uh....

in my thought, 
**process.standardInput = URL(txtfileURL)**

it should have worked but only errors...

Hmmmm...should i **cat textfile** and pass it to program....?

what should i do?
i really appreciate all your answers and helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`process.standardInput` requires an `FileHandle` or `Pipe`; a `URL` is neither of these - hence your errors.

Now consider that a `URL` represents the *location* of your file, while an `FileHandle` represents an *open channel* over which a file can be read and/or written. How do you get from the former to the latter? Usually some sort of "open a channel to this file" operation is provided. Take a look at the `FileHandle` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filehandle) and you should find a suitable `init` function to meet your needs. HTH

Comment: i didnt know filehandle is there. now i know one more thing. thanks!